# Accurate percentage in C++

Tags: c++

Given 2 numbers, where `A <= B` say for example `A = 9` and `B = 10`, I am trying to get the percentage of how smaller A is compared to B. I need to have the percentage as an `int` e.g. if the result is 10.00% The `int` should be 1000.

Here is my code:

```
int A = 9;
int B = 10;

int percentage = (((1 - (double)A/B) / 0.01)) * 100;
```

My code returns 999 instead of 1000. Some precision related to the usage of `double` is lost.

Is there a way to avoid losing precision in my case?

Comment: try getting it in a float variable and cast it to int. works for me. float percentage = (((1 - (double)A/B) / 0.01)) * 100; cout<< (int)percentage;  displays 1000

Comment: @VivekVK Using float may work for some values and doesn't solve the root issue.

Comment: @Vivek V K: it works even if percentage is `double`... Not sure why really...

Comment: Your calculation seems a bit overly complicated.  What's wrong with the simpler `((B-A) / (double)B) * 100.0`? Note also that 0.01 cannot be represented precisely in floating point formats, and so introduces some errors in the calculation as you're written it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems the formula you're looking for is

```
int result = 10000 - (A*10000+B/2)/B;
```

The idea is to do all computations in integers and delaying division.

To do the rounding half of the denominator is added before performing the division (otherwise you get truncation in the division and thus upper rounding because of 100%-x)

For example with A=9 and B=11 the percentage is 18.18181818... and rounding 18.18, the computation without the rounding would give 1819 instead of the expected result 1818.

Note that the computation is done all in integers so there is a risk of overflow for large values of `A` and `B`. For example if `int` is 32 bit then `A` can be up to around 200000 before risking an overflow when computing `A*10000`.

Using `A*10000LL` instead of `A*10000` in the formula will trade in some speed to raise the limit to a much bigger value.

Comment: Earlier you posted `10000 - A * 10000 / B` while this worked it did some rounding. Can you explain why are you adding `+B/2`?

Comment: (+1) This solution would perform faster (with perfect precision) than OP on CPUs that aren't good at floating point calculation.

Comment: Bear in mind that this will only work for smallish values of `A` (large values risk overflowing when doing `A * 10000 + B/2`

Comment: @MattMcNabb: added a note about overflow risk

Answer (score 2):

Offcourse there may be precision loss in floating point number. Either you should use fixed point number as @6502 answered or add a bias to the result to get the intended answer.
You should better do

```
assert(B != 0);
int percentage = ((A<0) == (B<0) ? 0.5 : -0.5) + (((1 - (double)A/B) / 0.01)) * 100;
```

Because of precision loss, result of `(((1 - (double)A/B) / 0.01)) * 100` may be slightly less or more than intended. If you add extra `0.5`, it is guaranteed to be sligthly more than intended. Now  when you cast this value to an integer, you get intended answer. (floor or ceil value depending whether the fractional part of the result of equation was above or below 0.5)

Comment: [this](http://floating-point-gui.de/) link provides some info about the behaviour of floating point numbers.

Comment: note, this would need modification in order to use it with negative numbers

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
float floatpercent = (((1 - (double)A/B) / 0.01)) * 100;
int percentage = (int) floatpercent;
cout<< percentage;
```

displays 1000

I suspect a precision loss on automatic casting to int as the root problem to your code.

Answer (score 0):

[*I alluded to this in a comment to the original question, but I though I'd post it as an answer.*]

The core problem is that the form of expression you're using amplifies the unavoidable floating point loss of precision when representing simple fractions of 10.

Your expression (with casts stripped out for now, using standard precedence to also avoid some parens)

```
((1 - A/B) / 0.01) * 100
```

is quite a complicated way of representing what you want, although it's *algebraically* correct.  Unfortunately, floating point numbers can only precisely represent numbers like 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, etc, their multiples, and sums of those.  In particular, neither 9/10 or 1/10 or 1/100 have precise representations.

The above expression introduces these errors twice: first in the calculation of `A/B`, and then in the division by `0.01`.  These two imprecise values are then divided, which further amplifies the inherent error.

The most direct way to write what you meant (again without needed casts) is

```
((B-A) / B) * 10000
```

This produces the correct answer and considerably easier to read, I would suggest, than the original.  The fully correct C form is

```
((B - A) / (double)B) * 10000
```

I've tested this and it works reliably.  As others have noted, it's generally good better to work with doubles instead of floats, as their extra precision makes them less prone (but not immune) to this sort of difficulty.